# Can't use chrome,brave,edge

Tags: google-chrome, browser, brave

I am getting error while I am searching anything

Error "Something went wrong while displaying this web page
Error code: SIGBUS(7)"

I saw some answers but I can't even access the settings tab can someone help me with it or can someone tell me how to get the settings tab of both browser

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I have disabled my hardware acceleration in chrome still doesn't work, and still can't access the brave settings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656263/whats-exactly-meaning-of-fatal-signal-7-sigbus-at-0x5937abd0-code-2-on-an